# Reemplazar headers de API Gateway mediante Lambda

Tags: api, aws, lambda, headers

Amig@s, el escenario es el siguiente: necesito *setear* de forma dinámica el nombre de un archivo `csv` en el `Content-Disposition` a través de `API Gateway`. 
Actualmente tengo una función lambda que devuelve el body correspondiente, pero al momento de exportarlo no he podido lograr reemplazar el nombre del csv.
He averiguado sobre las configuración de integración tanto de solicitud como respuesta pero no he podido dar en el clavo.

Habría alguna manera de reemplazar mediante lambda los `headers` de un `request|response` configurados en el API Gateway?

> PD: Cabe destacar que el tipo de integración de API Gateway es
>   "Función Lambda"

Les dejo el código de mi función por si lo necesitan

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-east-1' })

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (typeof event.query.conversation_id === 'undefined') throw new Error('Parameter: undefined [conversation_id]')
  if (typeof event.query.target === 'undefined') throw new Error('Parameter: undefined [target]')


  var params = {
    TableName: '<table>',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':conversation_id': event.query.conversation_id,
      ':target': event.query.target
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: 'conversation_id = :conversation_id',
    FilterExpression: 'conversation_id = :conversation_id and target = :target'
  }

  let data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    docClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Unable to query. Error:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
        reject(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Query succeeded.')
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })

  let logs = data.Items
  let conversation = []
  let arrMessages = logs[0].mensajes
  let conv

  for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
    let n = 0
    let arrFound = arrMessages.find(function (element) {
      n++
      return (element.from.type == 'Agent')
    })

    if (arrFound) {
      let cliente = false
      for (let j = n; j < arrMessages.length; j++) {
        if (arrMessages[j].from.type === 'Client') {
          cliente = true
        }
      }

      if (cliente) {
        conv = logs[i]
        break
      }
    }
  }

  const response = {}

  conv.mensajes.forEach(message => {
    if (message.from && message.text && message.type == "Message" && message.from.type == "Agent") {

      let clock = conv.timestamp
      clock = new Date(clock)
      clock.setHours(clock.getHours() - 4)
      let fecha = clock
      let hour = clock.getHours()
      let min = clock.getMinutes()
      let sec = clock.getSeconds()
      clock = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec
      conversation.push(['Agente', message.text.replace(/\n/g, ''), clock, fecha])
    }

    if (message.from && message.text && message.type == "Message" && message.from.type == "Client") {

      let clock = conv.timestamp
      clock = new Date(clock)
      clock.setHours(clock.getHours() - 4)
      let fecha = clock
      let hour = clock.getHours()
      let min = clock.getMinutes()
      let sec = clock.getSeconds()
      clock = hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec
      conversation.push(['Cliente', message.text.replace(/\n/g, ''), clock, fecha])
    }
  })

  const body = conversation.map(interaction => interaction.join(';'))
  response.body = body
  response.conversation_id = event.query.conversation_id
  var res = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
      'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${event.query.conversation_id}.csv`
    },
    body: response.body,
    isBase64Encoded: false
  }
  callback(null, res)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo también tuve el mismo problema lo solucione agregando esto en la configuración del serverless.yml

```
Content-Type: integration.response.body.type
Content-Disposition: integration.response.body.filename
```

y tienes que modificar el response de tu lambda

```
response = {
      body: conversation.map(interaction => interaction.join(';')),
      type: 'text/csv',
      filename: `attachment;filename=${event.query.conversation_id}.csv`
    }
```

Saludos, espero esto trabaje para ti.